# Is there a way for Windows 10 to adjust to a new monitor without rebooting?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1803

I typically plug my laptop into a dock which connects to 2 monitors (1920x1080 each).  While it's plugged in to the dock, the laptop monitor (2560x1440 with 150% scaling) is off.

When I disconnect from the dock, the screen on the laptop monitor switches back on and all is good.  Except there are inconsistencies all over the system, like fonts are different between context menu and its sub menu (see example below).

If I reboot the laptop, all fonts return to normal.  However, is there a way to have Windows auto-adjust (or maybe with the help of a script?) to the new monitor without having to reboot?

[image]

Comment: Are you running the Spring Creators Update? DPI scaling was improved in 1803.

Comment: @plttn Yes, using 1803.